# Submit a hadoop Job from PHP Web Application

Tags: php, hadoop

I'm developing a PHP application in which the user can provide parameters for a new job and then he could submit it to a hadoop cluster. My problem is that I was looking for some kind of "Job scheduler" what I could use in my PHP application but I haven't found one yet. Does anyone know how to deal with this? So the question: How can I submit a Job to a hadoop cluster from my PHP application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the WebHCat REST API to POST various job types from PHP.  The WebHCat API docs can be found at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference

Any HTTP client library can typically handle connecting to a REST endpoint, but it looks like there's an active project on github to make calling REST from PHP more approachable: https://github.com/educoder/pest